# How to get comment id in callback function?

Tags: comments

I am trying to get the comment ID in the custom callback function that I can use in wp-list_comments. Any help on how to do this? 
Thanks in advance

I am using wp_list_comments as: 
        `wp_list_comments('avatar_size=60&type=comment&callback=get_the_rating');`

Note: I was trying to use arguments earlier but I am not sure if I can use arguments in callback functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback is already passed arguments but crazily [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) doesn't document them. However it does give you an example and the first two lines are:

```
function mytheme_comment($comment, $args, $depth) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
```

which matches the equivalent functions in the bundled styles. Once you've set the comment object passed as the global as in that example then you're then free to use `get_comment_ID()` as usual.

If you didn't want to set the global then

```
$my_comment_ID = apply_filters( 'get_comment_ID', $comment->comment_ID );
```

is equivalent, but it's probably safer to go through `get_comment_ID()`.